# How do I use both Data and DataJson property of AdaptiveSubmitAction in Webchat channel

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I am using Adaptive Card SDK in Microsoft Bot Framework for Webchat. Code for my adaptive card submit button looks like :

```
var action_nothanks = new AdaptiveSubmitAction
{
Title = "No, Thanks",
Type = "Action.Submit",
DataJson = "{ \"action\":\"" + "No,Thanks" + ":" + "false" + "\"}"
};
```

This doesn't display the user selected value until I use "Data" property instead of "DataJson".
But, I want to use as following:

```
var action_nothanks = new AdaptiveSubmitAction
{
Title = "No, Thanks",
Type = "Action.Submit",
Data = "No, Thanks",
DataJson = "{ \"action\":\"" + "No,Thanks" + ":" + "false" + "\"}"
};
```

So that user selected value is displayed as "No, Thanks" while bot is returned "false".

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution is by adding the `displayText` and`action` properties from the `Data` object.
Below is the modified  AdaptiveSubmitAction code :

```cs
var action_nothanks = new AdaptiveSubmitAction
{
    Title = "No, Thanks",
    Type = "Action.Submit",
    Data = new { displayText = "No, Thanks", action = "No,Thanks:false" }
};
```

With a sample bot code, I was able to get both the properties from the data object.

So, when you receive the submitted action, The user-selected value will be displayed as "No, Thanks", while the bot will receive the "false" value.
[image]

Bot is created with [Echo Bot Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp,vscode) and modified with required `AdaptiveCards` code snippet.